# Can dapper indicate if there is a field name mismatch?

Tags: c#, dapper

```
class MyClass =
{ int Idx; }

sql = "SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE"
```

If I use this sql and class with dapper Idx won't be populated and there will be no errors.

If a field name of the query does not match the field name of the class dapper does not indicate any errors, it silently finishes the call (of course without populating Idx).

Is there a setting on dapper to get an error in this case?

Comment: AFAIK no, there is no such option. But this is more a problem of testing than a problem of missing functionality in dapper.

Comment: AFAIK no. You can make Idx nullable so you would be forced to check each time before using Idx. But I wouldn't recommend it. I guess this type of question would be more of a symptom of a problem. What is the real problem, is it that when developing you want to find mistakes faster or is in production and someone had the great idea of changing the return of a query / stored proc.

Comment: Is 'Id' a valid column in MyTable?

Comment: You can change the query something like: $"Select {nameof(MyClass.Idx)} from MyTable"

Comment: @Popa Andrei - yes this would work, if you would add this as answer I would accept it

Comment: @Jonathan Hickey - we are about to use this framework and I would like to be prepared for both cases

Comment: @RM. *could it* in theory? yes; but - no such option exists currently. I realise that this has already been said - I just wanted to add a definitive/authoritative "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can change the query something like: $"Select {nameof(MyClass.Idx)} from MyTable".

Answer (score 0):

Stack doesn't like you answering questions with programs, but my answer to this problem is a VS extension, [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst#overview). It generates the result class directly from the query, whenever you save the query, so the result class is guaranteed to match what the query returns (column names and data types). There are [numerous other advantages](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1108776/%2FTips%2F1108776%2FYour-SQL-Wrapped-in-Generated-Code-Interesting-Ori), but that's probably the main one. Disclaimer: I wrote QueryFirst.